# Getting 500 with little information in logs (heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails app deployed on Heroku working fine but when I get 500 I'm not able to know the reason as Heroku logs --tail not showing the full error messages.

I just made a dummy 500 error by

```sh
def puts_user_info
 email = user.first.email
 return render json: {data: email}, status: :ok
end
```

on local-Dev I'm getting `undefined local variable or method 'user'` which is fine but on heroku logs I just got

```
2021-07-08T08:47:38.948711+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="//customer_app/api/v1/puts/user/info" host=eaterybook-backend-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=6e224c0a-d874-45c4-882f-b5b0f1030972 fwd="119.155.23.119" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=920ms status=500 bytes=243 protocol=https
```

in my gemlist I have installed gem rails_12factor and in my production.rb I have

```sh
  config.log_level = :debug

  config.log_tags = [:request_id]

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end
```

And in my heroku config vars

```sh
LOG_LEVEL = DEBUG
RACK_ENV =  production
RAILS_ENV = production
RAILS_LOG_LEVEL = DEBUG
RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT = enabled
```

Comment: "undefined local variable or method 'user' which is fine" - in what world is it ok that you're getting a reference error?

Comment: im trying to say that im getting full error message on local but on heroku (production) I'm  just getting 500 with no other message that from where this error is occurring or full error message